# How to setup Django silk profiler

Tags: python, django, profiling

I am completely new to Django and profiling. I have completed all the steps mentioned in the document for setting up the silk profiler.
https://github.com/jazzband/silk
I did not find any error when I ran the manage.py run server command
But when I open the browser and call the necessary api, I don't find anything related to silk. I have no idea where to find the results. Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: You haven't mentioned what all steps you followed? To help, we need whatever you did and which necessary api you called?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just went through the beginning with silk.
As a result:

Settings.py:

```
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'silk',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'silk.middleware.SilkyMiddleware',


    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]




# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/


STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static_in_env")

#before you change this make sure to create a folder "static" in project directory, otherwise it will throw an error.

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
        os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
        ]



STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

IN urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf.urls import include

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^silk/', include('silk.urls', namespace='silk')),
]
```

(Assumimg you are on linux)Now run:

```
python manage.py makemigrations;

python manage.py migrate;

python manage.py collectstatic;
```

then run the server and go to

127.0.0.1:8000/silk/

url

Answer (score 1):

Django SILK

```
pip install django-silk
```

---

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    ...
    'silk.middleware.SilkyMiddleware',
    ...
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'silk'
)
```

---

```
urlpatterns += patterns('', url(r'^silk', include('silk.urls', namespace='silk')))
```

---

```
python manage.py syncdb
```

---

Profilling

Decorator applied to views.

Function based:

```
@silk_profile(name='View Blog Post')
def post(request, post_id):
    p = Post.objects.get(pk=post_id)
    return render_to_response('post.html', {
        'post': p
    })
```

Class based:

```
class MyView(View):
        @silk_profile(name='View Blog Post')
        def get(self, request):
                p = Post.objects.get(pk=post_id)
        return render_to_response('post.html', {
                'post': p
        })
```

---

Context Manager

```
def post(request, post_id):
    with silk_profile(name='View Blog Post #%d' % self.pk):
        p = Post.objects.get(pk=post_id)
        return render_to_response('post.html', {
                'post': p
        })
```

And

```
python manage.py makemigrations;

python manage.py migrate;

python manage.py collectstatic;
```